# How do I setup my python email alerting function such that if no files are present in my source directory,then, i dont receive the email?

Tags: python, pandas, path, glob

My script currently works to send me an error alert if my .py script fails. However, sometimes the script is not necessarily failing. its just that there are no files for it to process. My final objective is to alter my email alerting script in such a way that if Combine.csv is not present in directory(src),then DONT send me error an email. How do i achieve this?

```
import pandas as pd
import smtplib
from email.message import EmailMessage
import glob
import os
import shutil
df = pd.read_fwf(r'Combine.csv', header=None)
end_str = '#--- END --'
cols_to_check = ["0"]


def email_alert(subject,body,to):
    msg = EmailMessage()
    msg.set_content(body)
    msg['subject'] = subject
    msg['to'] = to
        
    user = "DataScienceScriptAlerts@afonsfu.com"
    msg['from'] = user
    
        
    server = smtplib.SMTP("smtpray.corp.group.com", 25)
    server.starttls()
    #server.login(user,password)
    server.send_message(msg)
        
    server.quit()
src = r'C:/R'
dest = r'C:/R/Failed Scripts'
if __name__ == '__main__':

    for col in cols_to_check:
        if not df[0].str.contains(end_str).any():
            body = "The Combine.py script in IV had errors on the last execution" + col + "."
            print(body)
            email_alert("Combine failure alert",body,"htvldba@group.com")
        if not df[0].str.contains(end_str).any():
                for file_path in glob.glob(os.path.join(src,'*.Rout'), recursive=True):
                    new_path = os.path.join(dest, os.path.basename(file_path))
                    shutil.copy(file_path, new_path)
```

Comment: Can you check if the file exists and skip sending email if it doesn't? https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.isfile

Comment: CSV file literally has only #--- END --

Comment: @APorter1031 that strategy works, but how do i implement that in my current code. Still a rookie at this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check whether the file you want to read exists:

```
import os
file_name = "Combine.csv"
cwd = os.getcwd()
file_path = os.path.join(cwd, file_name)
if not os.path.exists(file_path):
   exit()
```

cwd means current working directory and is the path to the directory your python file runs in. Then path.join just combines your file name with the path to your directory so that you have an absolute path. Then you can check whether than file exists using the path.exist function.

Comment: If you're looking in the current directory, you don't need a path at all.  Just use the bare filename.

Comment: Thank you for posting your answer Nick. 2 questions -  1) Where do I place your part of the code in my code? At the beginning? before 
def email_alert(subject,body,to):? 2) If I do this, and someday the file exists in the directory, will i get an email if --END--- exists in it?

Comment: You would just put it right at the beginning of the file, right after the imports somewhere. No reason to run the rest of the code if there is no file, right? Yes it just ends the code right there if the file does NOT exists. Otherwise is does nothing and the remaining code is run.

Comment: @nick question: How can i edit your code such that it is not filename specific. so basically if any file exists in filepath then send the email, if no file exists in filepath then dont send the email alert

Comment: You can list the contents of a director with `dir = os.listdir(path)` and then check whether it is empty and exit if it is: `if len(dir) == 0: exit()`

Answer (score 0):

To eliminate inspection of what the 'end' terminator, we can evaluate the size of the dataframe and exit the loop (or script) if appropriate.

```py
if len(df) == 1:
    break  # exit()
```

The `break` keyword may be ideal if exiting a loop. However, if the data is pulled from `combine.csv`, then `exit()` to terminate the script may be more appropriate.